# From a MySQL client connection, how can I determine which MySQL server is in use? (e.g. MySQL or MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I maintain an [opensource project](https://github.com/pglombardo/PasswordPusher) that supports multiple database backends.  Users can either MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres etc..

There is a variation in behaviour between MySQL and MariaDB and I need to determine which database server is in use.

*Given a MySQL connection only*: how can I determine which MySQL server flavor I am talking to?  MySQL or MariaDB?  Is there a magic SQL query?

Note: `select version();` does not provide any info on whether we are speaking with a MySQL or MariaDB server.

Comment: Have you tried `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show variables like 'version%';
```

MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/jiksphR2

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| version | 8.0.30 |
| version_comment | MySQL Community Server - GPL |

MariaDB: https://dbfiddle.uk/o_jYif0i

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| version | 10.6.9-MariaDB-1:10.6.9+maria~deb11 |
| version_comment | mariadb.org binary distribution |

There are additional version variables for the OS, the architecture, and so on, but these two above are the most relevant.